# Remove the bullet list on the last button

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

I want to remove the bullet list on the last button in my wordpress childtheme.
I tried to use `#access ul li:last-child a{ background-image:none;}` but it didn´t remove the bg picture on the last button.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c51wykb72

Any easy way to solve that?

Comment: Post your relevant, minimal ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) code *here*, and demos/reproductions of your problem in a site in which we can both *see* and *easily experiment with* the relevant HTML, CSS and/or JavaScript, such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The background image is not on the anchor tag. It's on the li.

```
ul.menu li:last-child {background-image:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your background image isn't actually on the < a > it's on the li.

```
li:last-child{background-image:none!important}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Asker of question didn't provide a jsfiddle, and I wasn't sure of any previous styles that would have conflicted with the above styles.

So I added !important at the end to override anything that may have come in conflict.